# Twig one to many relations

Tags: twig

I am new to Twig. I thought I had mastered the basics but am completely stuck on this.

I have two arrays:

```
books => [
             [
                 'book_id' => ...,
                 'book_title' => ...,
             ],
         ],
```

and

```
tags => [
             [
                 'tag_id' => ...,
                 'book_id' => ...,
                 'tag'     => ...,
             ],
         ],
```

How do I get Twig to produce something along these lines

> Book title 1   tag1 tag2 tag3 tag5
>
> Book title 2   tag1 tag3 tag4 tag2

and so on

So far I have

```
{% for book in books %}
    {{book.title}} 
    {% for tag in tags %}

what goes here to get a list of tags for this book

    {%endfor%}  
{% endfor %}
```

I know it is only a few lines of code but I don’t know where to start
A  hint in the right direction would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you know the book_id. You should be able to use this to limit your FOR loop over the Tags:

```
{% for book in books %}
    {{book.title}} 
    {% for tag in tags if book.id == tag.id %}
       {{ tag.tag }}
    {%endfor%}  
{% endfor %}
```

See: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#adding-a-condition

Comment: Thanks very much for your speedy reply. You have saved me hours trying to work it out.